# detect max width of each element in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do this exact function in angular and doesn't work at all, my elements are hidden by ngIf then looping the elements.

this is how is done in jquery:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply( null, $( 'div' ).map( function () {
    return $( this ).outerWidth( true );
}).get() );

alert( maxWidth );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rM4UG/

How should be in angular?

Comment: you cannot measure width of something that hidden with ngIf since those elements simply not exist on the dom

Comment: indeed I can't measure, but I can do it after if visible, but after this flag is set to true, the code won't work properly, I don't see any other solution, only a jquery function

Comment: how about hide elements with [hidden]=true?